# Como obter o Thread Stack?

Tags: c++, thread, stack

Estou tentando criar um programa para obter os thread stack, igual o da imagem, alguem tem alguma maneira de como obter isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada no código do process hacker que está no github :
https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker

Lá tem o arquivo chamado [thread.c](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/KProcessHacker/thread.c)
 com um conteúdo bastante complexo pois ele interage com o Kernel do Windows com o objetivo de fazer exatamente o'que você quer, obter o Thread stack. Mas o código está bem comentado, então espero que te ajude. Lembrando que talvez seja necessário que você leia outros arquivos do projeto para compreender melhor o funcionamento do programa.

Comment: Pois é, eu baixei a source completa do Process Hacker para entender como ele obtem a thread Stack, mas o código era tão grande e completo que acabei desistindo, mas vou tentar mais, olhando esse thread.c